# Java Streams - Are you able to have multiple terminal operations (e.g. forEach)

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm fairly new to Java and trying to learn how to use streams for easier code writing.  If I can code like this:

```java
Map<String, SomeConfig> temp = new HashMap<>();

resultStorage.forEach((key, value) -> key.getUsers().forEach(user -> {
    if (!temp.containsKey(user.getMeta())) {

        SomeConfig emailConfiguration = key
            .withCheck1(masterAccountId)
            .withCheck2(getClientTimezone())
            .withCheck3(user.getMeta());

        temp.put(user.getMeta(), emailConfiguration);
    }

    temp.get(user. getMeta()).getStreams().add(value);

}));

return new ArrayList<>(temp.values());
```

`resultStorage` declaration:

```java
private Map< SomeConfig, byte[]> resultStorage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

`getStreams` is a getter on `SomeConfig` that returns a `List<byte[]>` as here:

```java
    private List<byte[]> attachmentStreams = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<byte[]> getAttachmentStreams() {
        return attachmentStreams;
    }
```

My first attempt was something similar to this:

```java
resultStorage.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(entry -> entry.getKey().getUsers().forEach(user -> {
                            
    }));
```

Are we able to use a forEach within one of the streams terminating operation, forEach?  How would a stream benefit in this case as I saw documentation that it can significantly improve readability and performance of older pre-Java8 code?

**Edit:**
`resultStorage` holds a ConcurrentHashMap.  It will contain `Map<SomeConfig, byte[]>` for email and attachments. Using another HashMap `temp` that is initially empty - we analyze `resultStorage` , see if `temp` contains a specific email key, and then `put` or `add` based on the existence of a user's email

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `within one of the streams terminating forEach`

Comment: Is the `forEach` when using the Stream API considered a terminating operation?  Referencing a tutorial I saw.  `resultStorage.entrySet().stream()
                        .forEach((....`

Comment: For others reference:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1-YZ6bF-g0&t=190s

Comment: @RobertHarvey The tutorial probably meant terminal operation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He means "terminal operation", which is a standard term in the Streams-API. It's even in the docs for forEach: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: @TeemoSays234 Please describe the logic you are trying to implement. It hard to grasp just from your examples. Preferably give some example input with corresponding output.

Comment: You cannot use a terminal operation twice, as them being terminal by definition means they consume the stream. There are, however, intermediate operations that can be performed in a similar manner (see: `Stream#peek`)

Comment: @Holder updated for additional clarity

Comment: For learning streams, I suggest the following (in no particular order): [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) (Article in Oracle Magazine by Urma), [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), Oracle's [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html). Also, in my opinion, the book [Core Java](https://horstmann.com/corejava/), by Horstmann contains an excellent explanation of streams.

Comment: There are **many** questions (with answers) regarding Java streams on this Web site. Just enter `[java] stream` into the search box at the top of this Web page. Also, consider posting a [mcve]. I think that will help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal operation of `entrySet().stream().forEach(…)` is entirely unrelated to the `getUsers().forEach(…)` call within the `Consumer`. So there’s no problem of “multiple terminal operations” here.

However, replacing the `Map` operation `forEach((key, value) -> …` with an `entrySet() .stream() .forEach(entry -> …)` rarely adds a benefit. So far, you’re not only made the code longer, you introduced the necessity to deal with a `Map.Entry` instead of just using `key` and `value`.

But you can simplify your operation by using a single `computeIfAbsent` instead of `containsKey`, `put`, and `get`:

```java
resultStorage.forEach((key, value) -> key.getUsers().forEach(user ->
    temp.computeIfAbsent(user.getMeta(), meta ->
        key.withCheck1(masterAccountId).withCheck2(getClientTimezone()).withCheck3(meta))
    .getStreams().add(value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes after the code.

```java
Map<String, SomeConfig> temp = resultStorage.keySet()
                                            .stream()
                                            .flatMap(key -> key.getUsers()
                                                               .stream()
                                                               .map(user -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(user, key)))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getMeta(),
                                                                      e -> e.getValue()
                                                                            .withCheck1(masterAccountId)
                                                                            .withCheck2(getClientTimezone())
                                                                            .withCheck3(e.getKey().getMeta())
```

---

```java
resultStorage.keySet()
```

This returns `Set<SomeConfig>`.

```java
stream()
```

This returns a stream where every element in the stream is an instance of `SomeConfig`.

```java
.flatMap(key -> key.getUsers()
                   .stream()
                   .map(user -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(user, key)))
```

Method `flatMap()` must return a `Stream`. The above code returns a `Stream` where every element is an instance of [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). The "entry" key is the *user* and the entry value is the *key* from `resultStorage`.

Finally I create a `Map<String, SomeConfig>` via [static] method `toMap` of class [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

The first argument to method `toMap` is the *key mapper*, i.e. a method that extracts the [map] key from the `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`. In your case this is the value returned by method `getMeta()` of the *user* – which is the key from `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`, i.e. `e.getKey()` returns a *user* object.

The second argument to `toMap` is the *value mapper*. `e.getValue()` returns a `SomeConfig` object and the rest is your code, i.e. the `withCheck`s.

There is no way I can test the above code because not only did you not post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you also did not post any sample data. Hence the above may be *way off* what you actually require.

Also note that the above code simply creates your `Map<String, SomeConfig> temp`. I could not understand the code in your question that processes that `Map` so I did not try to implement that part at all.